# How to make GMail add-on's OAuth consent screen re-appear after add-on authorized?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth

Google has asked me to resubmit my GMail Add-on for verification, which includes making a video showing the OAuth consent screen.

But since I've already authorized the add-on on my machine, the OAuth consent screen doesn't appear when I use the add-on. I've tried to make the consent screen appear so I can take a video, but nothing has worked. Things I've tried:

- Uninstalling and re-installing the add-on (via Deploy > Test Deployments)
- Adding another scope, authorizing with that, removing the scope, and running the add-on

How can I make the consent screen appear?

Comment: Perhaps try finding your OAuth consent screen name at [myaccount.google.com/connections](https://myaccount.google.com/connections) & delete it. [See this official Google Docs](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/13533235)

Comment: Thanks @SputnikDrunk2 - that's the solution, and helpful to have the exact link! If you want to make an actual answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: You're welcome. I went ahead and added this comment as an answer for your post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

If you want to reset and re-authenticate OAuth for your app through your Google account, follow these steps:

1. Visit [myaccount.google.com/connections](https://myaccount.google.com/connections).
2. Locate your OAuth consent screen and delete it.

For additional information and detailed instructions, please refer to the [official Google article](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/13533235).

This process will help you effectively reset and re-authenticate OAuth for your app.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your code try removing consent in your Google account directly under third party apps